# Get rid of hours in React Line Chart

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, math

I want to get rid of every third hour from the bottom of the rope chart. I am using react-chart-js2. I am using .map function to display those numbers. Is any possible to show only every third of them?
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBR1C.png)

Here is the code for displaying those hours:

```
const data = {
       labels: chart.prices?.map(x => moment(x[0]).format('h:mm a')),
        datasets: [{
            data: chart.prices?.map(x => x[1]),
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff00',
            borderColor: 'rgb(79 70 229)',
            borderWidth: '2',
            pointBorderColor: '#ffffff00',
            tension: 0.4,
            fill: {
                target: "origin", // 3. Set the fill options
                above: "rgba(79, 70, 229, 0.0625)"
            }
        }]
      }
```

I expect to show only third of those numbers

Answer (score 0):

Replace every third item with an empty string.

```
let hours = chart.prices?.map(x => moment(x[0]).format('h:mm a'));

for (let i=0; i<=hours.length; i++) {
  if((i+1) % 3 == 0){
        hours[i] = "";
  }
}
```

then in chart.js:

`labels: hours,`